# Join 2 tables with different values

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 MySQL tables: table1 and table2
The field "table1.name" has records like "category.1298" where the number after the dot comes from the field ID in table2.
I would like to join table2.ID with table1.name to identify whether table2.ID is equal to the number (after the dot) in table1.name

The question is how to eliminate the portion "category." in table1.name

Comment: The question is how to eliminate the portion "category." in table1.name

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Tell us if you have tried anything, if so, then tell us about it and what went wrong with it. If not, then try doing something first and then if you are stuck and don't understand anything tells us about it. About the comment above, add it to the question by [edit]ing.

Answer (score 1):

`substring_index` is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.id, '.', -1) = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring_index

`Select substring_index(table1.name,'.',-1)` returns 1298

```
select *
from table1, table2
where substring_index(table1.name,'.',-1) = table2.id
```